# warning: assignment from incompatible pointer type for linklist array

Tags: c, compiler-warnings, incompatibletypeerror

I am executing a C program where I am getting warning:
warning: assignment from incompatible pointer type

I am copying related code herein:

```
//Structure I am using:

typedef struct graph_node
{
    int id;
    int weight;
    struct node *next;
}node, dummy;

node *head[10];

// Function which is generating this warning:
void print_list()
{
    int i;

    for (i = 0;i< vertex; i++)
    {
        printf ("\n ==>>%d ", head[i]->id);

        while (head[i]->next != NULL)
        {
            head[i] = head[i]->next;
            printf ("\t ==>>%d ", head[i]->id); /******This line is     generating warning  ********/
        }   
    }
}
```

Above code compiles fine with throws the warning below:

> warning: assignment from incompatible pointer type for linklist array

Answer (score 3):

You should not write `struct node *next;` as `node` is not `typedef`ed yet and `struct node` simply does not exist.

You should re-declare your structure as:

```
typedef struct graph_node
{
    int id;
    int weight;
    struct graph_node *next;
    /*     ^^^^^^           */
}node, dummy;
```

**Why does my code compile then**

When you write just `struct node *next;`, your compiler assumes `struct node` is an incomplete type (declaration only) and allows the pointer to this type.

When you convert the pointer of type `struct node` to `node` (which is a `typedef` of `struct graph_node`), the incompatible pointer conversion warning occurs to warn you from any strict aliasing rule break or similar other issues.

Is assuming `struct node` to be an incomplete type is little broad and a separate question.

And yes, the warning is being thrown for the line `head[i] = head[i]->next;` and not the next one :)

Answer (score 0):

check this code.i think it will probably work.and post the complete code so i can resolve complete.

```
 typedef struct graph_node
{
    int id;
    int weight;
    struct node *next;
}node, dummy;
node *head[10];

// Function which is generating this warning:

void print_list()
{
int i;
    for (i = 0;i< vertex; i++)
    {
        printf ("\n ==>>%d ", head[i]->id);
        while (head[i]->next->next != NULL)
        {
            head[i] = head[i]->next;
         printf ("\t ==>>%d ", head[i]->id); 
               if(head[i]->next==NULL)
{
            printf ("\t ==>>%d ", head[i]->id); 

}

        }   
    }
}
```