# Scope of forward-declared struct

Tags: c, scope, language-lawyer, c11

Imagine we have this:

```
void f(struct s *);
```

From reading the standard ($6.2.1) I'm kinda confused at what is the scope of tags. First there is this:

> 3. A label name is the only kind of identifier that has function scope. It can be used (in a
>      goto statement) anywhere in the function in which it appears, and is declared implicitly
>      by its syntactic appearance (followed by a : and a statement).
> 4. Every other identifier has scope determined by the placement of its declaration (in a declarator or type specifier). If the declarator or
>      type specifier that declares the identifier appears outside of any
>      block or list of parameters, the identifier has file scope, which
>      terminates at the end of the translation unit. If the declarator or
>      type specifier that declares the identifier appears inside a block or
>      within the list of parameter declarations in a function definition,
>      the identifier has block scope, which terminates at the end of the
>      associated block. **If the declarator or type specifier that declares
>      the identifier appears within the list of parameter declarations in a
>      function prototype (not part of a function definition), the identifier
>      has function prototype scope, which terminates at the end of the
>      function declarator.** If an identifier designates two different
>      entities in the same name space, the scopes might overlap. If so, the
>      scope of one entity (the inner scope) will end strictly before the
>      scope of the other entity (the outer scope). Within the inner scope,
>      the identifier designates the entity declared in the inner scope; the
>      entity declared in the outer scope is hidden (and not visible) within
>      the inner scope.

As identifier properties being early defined as:

> 1. **An identifier can denote** an object; a function; **a tag or a member of a structure**, union, or enumeration; a typedef name; a label name; a
>      macro name; or a macro parameter. The same identifier can denote
>      different entities at different points in the program. A member of an
>      enumeration is called an enumeration constant. Macro names and macro
>      parameters are not considered further here, because prior to the
>      semantic phase of program translation any occurrences of macro names
>      in the source file are replaced by the preprocessing token sequences
>      that constitute their macro definitions.

Which leads me to this conclusion:

As the type specifier `struct s` declares the identifier `s` within "the list of parameter declarations in a function prototype" it has (the identifier `s`) function prototype scope. Which means something like this:

```
void f2()
{ //inside **some** function block after the above declaration
    struct s { int a; } v; //new s identifier being declared

    f(&v); //not compatible types
}
```

But then after this we have:

> 7. **Structure, union, and enumeration tags have scope that begins just after the appearance of the tag in a type specifier that declares the
>      tag.** Each enumeration constant has scope that begins just after the
>      appearance of its defining enumerator in an enumerator list. Any other
>      identifier has scope that begins just after the completion of its
>      declarator.

Which means something entirely different:

```
void f3()
{ //inside **some** function block after the above declaration
    struct s { int a; } v; //completing incomplete type

    f(&v); //ok
}
```

Seems like gcc and clang follows p4 (summered up with this warning of compiling the declaration of `f`):

```
warning: ‘struct s’ declared inside parameter list will not be visible outside of this definition or declaration
void f(struct s *);
```

Similar is the case using clang:

```
warning: declaration of 'struct s' will not be visible outside of this function [-Wvisibility]
void f(struct s *);
```

Anyone care to explain what is the right way to determine the scope of the `s` identifier in the function prototype `f`?

I'm referring to INCITS/ISO/IEC 9899-2011[2012] standard paper; compiling with gcc compiler (and clang) with the following flags:

```
-std=c11 -pedantic
```

Request for a complete piece of code:

Currently (by compiling with GCC and clang) this:

```
void f(struct s {int _;});

struct s g;
```

Will give the following error (by clang):

```
prog.c:1:15: warning: declaration of 'struct s' will not be visible outside of this function [-Wvisibility]
void f(struct s {int _;});
              ^
prog.c:3:10: error: tentative definition has type 'struct s' that is never completed
struct s g; 
         ^
prog.c:3:8: note: forward declaration of 'struct s'
struct s g;
```

Which by quoting the standard may or may not be the right behavior in the case (conflicting p4 and p7 - or are they? - I don't know).

By p7 `struct s` in the declaration of `g` should refer to the same identifier declared in the function prototype of `f`. And so there shouldn't be any compiler errors caused by defining a variable with incomplete type.

But by p4 `struct s` declared in the function prototype of `f` must have scope which terminates at the end of the function declarator. And so then the declaration of `struct s` in the declaration of `g` should create another identifier `s` (being a tag of incomplete structure and so the error messages).

Comment: Please provide us with a complete piece of code that shows the expected and the unexpected behavior and on what lines the errors/warnings are.

Comment: Related: http://stackoverflow.com/questions/30725769/all-struct-identifiers-are-automatically-forward-declared

Comment: @MohitJain Not exactly.

Comment: @FISOCPP I said related not duplicate.

Answer (score 1):

First and foremost, you are not allowed to *define* a class within a parameter list. I cannot find a compiler that will compile `void f(struct s {int _;});`, so perhaps you had a non-conforming one when you asked this question. You can find this rule in the standard at
[dcl.fct]:

> Types shall not be defined in return or parameter types.

Second, according to the C++03 (ISO/IEC 14882:2003) standard all the way through C++17 (N4659), the rules regarding a forward declaration of a type within a parameter list have not changed ([basic.scope.pdecl]):

> if the *elaborated-type-specifier* is used in the *decl-specifier-seq* or parameter-declaration-clause of a
>   function defined in namespace scope, the *identifier* is declared as a *class-name* in the namespace that
>   contains the declaration

Therefore the scope of the type that you forward declare within a function's parameter list is in the namespace of that function. You still must define the type before you use it. Code like the following is legal since C++03: [Demo](https://wandbox.org/permlink/zcnXrsEfLn6aztX7)

```
void f(struct s); // forward declares s
struct s{int i;}; // defines s forward declared above

void f(s a){ // use s
   std::cout << a.i << std::endl;
}

int main()
{
   s g;
   g.i = 0;
   f(g);
}
```

To more specifically answer your question, the `struct s` that you forward declare within function `f` has namespace scope.

Answer (score -1):

Difficult question. I am not a standard guru but maybe can shine some light on the behavior.

When you declare your function `f`, you give it a parameter of type `struct s` with a definition of that structure as `{int _;}`. The placement of this definition means the definition will not be visible outside this prototype declaration (I wonder how you could ever call `f`). The compiler flags this as a warning. Errors might be given later when using `f`.

Then you declare a variable of type `struct s` but since your earlier definition has already gone out of scope, and the compiler hasen't seen a definition of it earlier (before `f`) it flags an error about declaring a variable of which the compiler cannot calculate the size (the compiler must set aside memory here).

Lastly, older compilers were one-pass, meaning that it must be fed al information in a precise order, particularly that types must have been defined before variables of the type can be declared. Many current compilers are two-pass, meaning it scans the input text two times and now in the second pass must be able to complete the translation. The compiler flags to you an attempt of a "forward declaration" which can only be resolved in a second pass. To my knowledge the C language is specified for one-pass.

The only forward declaration possible in C is declaring a pointer to a type that has not been [completely] specified as the compiler knows the size of a pointer.